# Help identifying fonts used in this paper

Tags: fonts

Dr. Ravi Vakil's Algebraic Geometry notes use fonts that I really like; I was wondering if anyone knew off hand how to implement them. I could not find any source tex files unfortunately.

http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjan1412public.pdf

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear... I'm looking for both.

Comment: I'm almost positive the text font is Palatino.

Comment: Are you asking about the text font in use or the math font?The former is `Palatino`, the latter is likely either `Euler` or `Euler VM`.

Comment: Quite a remarkable cocktail of fonts. AFAICT, only missing Comic Sans and Windings2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Palatino with Euler for math.

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{euler}
```

Or if you want to use fontspec and Microsoft's (authorized) Palatino:

```
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}
\usepackage{euler}
```

Comment: Thank you! Also I appreciate including the code because I did not know how to change the fonts.

Comment: @aengle1429 You can check the font names used in a PDF by pressing CTRL+D in Acrobat and checking the fonts tab. But I don't know if this works in Adobe Reader (Acrobat Reader) also.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to discover which fonts are used in a document is the `pdffonts` command line tool. TeX Live has it available. A quick run with `pdffonts article.pdf`:

```
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
ZUOYML+CMSY9                         Type 1C           yes yes yes     11  0
CREMHH+Palatino-Roman                Type 1C           yes yes no       9  0
PKYDJG+Palatino-Bold                 Type 1C           yes yes no       8  0
FAPBTP+EURM7                         Type 1C           yes yes no      25  0
LORPOO+EURM10                        Type 1C           yes yes no      26  0
ZYDLZO+EUFM10                        Type 1C           yes yes no      27  0
BZWQQV+CMSY10                        Type 1C           yes yes no      28  0
RLJMGK+Palatino-Roman~118            Type 1C           yes yes no      29  0
RHNQIF+CMMI10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes     23  0
USPJFH+Palatino-Roman~de             Type 1C           yes yes no      20  0
LBXBQO+Palatino-Bold~e4              Type 1C           yes yes no      21  0
DCYFGC+rsfs10                        Type 1C           yes yes no      24  0
LORPOO+EURM10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    213  0
YNVCIJ+Courier                       TrueType          yes yes no     261  0
CALUQS+Palatino-Italic               Type 1C           yes yes no     259  0
OIKDGC+Palatino-Bold~1d7             Type 1C           yes yes no     260  0
BZWQQV+CMSY10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    272  0
MJIRVI+EUFM7                         Type 1C           yes yes yes    274  0
DCYFGC+Palatino-Bold~1f9             Type 1C           yes yes no     294  0
JKDHEY+Palatino-Bold~1f4             Type 1C           yes yes no     293  0
LUXACN+CMSY7                         Type 1C           yes yes yes    307  0
JKDHEY+EUSM10                        Type 1C           yes yes no     303  0
WQVIGW+EUEX10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    305  0
IUVTHW+EURM5                         Type 1C           yes yes no     321  0
OLDQQE+XYBTIP10                      Type 1C           yes yes yes    315  0
FAPBTP+EURM7                         Type 1C           yes yes yes    316  0
OLDQQE+XYATIP10                      Type 1C           yes yes yes    313  0
XWAZEU+CMSY5                         Type 1C           yes yes yes    318  0
MJIRVI+EUFM7                         Type 1C           yes yes no     273  0
AFCCUW+XYDASH10                      Type 1C           yes yes yes    320  0
BPJUER+Palatino-Roman~22b            Type 1C           yes yes no     338  0
TQSBKP+MSBM10                        Type 1C           yes yes no     339  0
SNJXWC+rsfs7                         Type 1C           yes yes no     359  0
JKDHEY+EUSM7                         Type 1C           yes yes yes    365  0
JKDHEY+EUSM10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    378  0
ZYDLZO+EUFM10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    389  0
TXCHMJ+MSBM7                         Type 1C           yes yes no     404  0
XWAZEU+MSAM10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    458  0
BZWQQV+CMEX10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    478  0
XWAZEU+EUEX10~2ac                    Type 1C           yes yes yes    476  0
ZWSMBL+EUFM5                         Type 1C           yes yes yes    503  0
LUXACN+CMSY7                         Type 1C           yes yes no     306  0
ZWSMBL+EUFM5                         Type 1C           yes yes no     502  0
ZUOYML+CMMI12                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    612  0
TLIMFT+EUEX10~337                    Type 1C           yes yes yes    624  0
MJIRVI+XYBSQL10                      Type 1C           yes yes yes    647  0
TQSBKP+MSBM10                        Type 1C           yes yes yes    751  0
SNJXWC+ZapfChancery-MediumItalic     Type 1C           yes yes no     791  0
ZYDLZO+Palatino-Italic~3d0           Type 1C           yes yes no     792  0
ZUOYML+rsfs5                         Type 1C           yes yes no     800  0
ZUOYML+rsfs10~413                    Type 1C           yes yes no     863  0
RLJMGK+EURM10~416                    Type 1C           yes yes no     864  0
WPQLPJ+CMMI7                         Type 1C           yes yes yes    963  0
RJQSHH+EUFM10~483                    Type 1C           yes yes no     983  0
RJQSHH+EUFM10~483                    Type 1C           yes yes yes    984  0
ZWSMBL+CMSY8                         Type 1C           yes yes no     995  0
CREMHH+EURM7~4bf                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1042  0
JKDHEY+MSBM10~4b9                    Type 1C           yes yes no    1040  0
ZWSMBL+EUFM7~4bc                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1041  0
WPQLPJ+MSBM7~4d7                     Type 1C           yes yes no    1073  0
SNJXWC+EURM10~512                    Type 1C           yes yes no    1130  0
JKDHEY+Palatino-Roman~50f            Type 1C           yes yes no    1129  0
ZUOYML+CMSY10~569                    Type 1C           yes yes no    1223  0
TLIMFT+EUFM10~566                    Type 1C           yes yes no    1222  0
ZWSMBL+CMSY8                         Type 1C           yes yes yes   1282  0
IUVTHW+EURM5                         Type 1C           yes yes yes   1283  0
EMGISR+Palatino-Roman~5c3            Type 1C           yes yes no    1326  0
EMGISR+Palatino-BoldItalic           Type 1C           yes yes no    1397  0
ZUOYML+CMMI5                         Type 1C           yes yes yes   1792  0
ZUOYML+CMR10                         Type 1C           yes yes no    1945  0
ZWSMBL+EUFM7~4bc                     Type 1C           yes yes yes   2260  0
RLJMGK+EURM10~416                    Type 1C           yes yes yes   2259  0
TLIMFT+EUSM10~b0c                    Type 1C           yes yes yes   2831  0
ZUOYML+MSAM7                         Type 1C           yes yes yes   2889  0
JKDHEY+EUSM7                         Type 1C           yes yes no     364  0
TXCHMJ+MSBM7                         Type 1C           yes yes yes   3876  0
ZUOYML+EURM10~f26                    Type 1C           yes yes no    4000  0
XWAZEU+CMSY5                         Type 1C           yes yes no     317  0
TXCHMJ+ZapfChancery-MediumItalic~1048 Type 1C           yes yes no    4327  0
JKDHEY+CMSY6                         Type 1C           yes yes yes   4460  0
ZUOYML+CMMI12~110c                   Type 1C           yes yes yes   4544  0
USPJFH+Palatino-Roman~de             Type 1C           yes yes yes   4719  0
ZUOYML+EUSM7~1207                    Type 1C           yes yes no    4821  0
ZUOYML+EUEX10~1204                   Type 1C           yes yes yes   4820  0
HGSIUG+Palatino-Roman~1201           Type 1C           yes yes no    4818  0
JKDHEY+CMSY6                         Type 1C           yes yes no    4459  0
WPQLPJ+rsfs5~120a                    Type 1C           yes yes no    4822  0
WPQLPJ+MSBM5                         Type 1C           yes yes no    5290  0
TLIMFT+rsfs10~153c                   Type 1C           yes yes no    5722  0
TLIMFT+EUSM10~b0c                    Type 1C           yes yes no    2830  0
SNJXWC+EURM10~512                    Type 1C           yes yes yes   6972  0
OLDQQE+Palatino-Italic~1a8b          Type 1C           yes yes no    6991  0
EMGISR+Palatino-Bold~1a8e            Type 1C           yes yes no    6992  0
DSBHCT+Courier                       TrueType          yes yes no    6997  0
BPJUER+Palatino-Roman~22b            Type 1C           yes yes yes   6998  0
ZUOYML+TeX-cmex8                     Type 1C           yes yes no    7005  0
ZUOYML+MSAM10~1acb                   Type 1C           yes yes yes   7004  0
CREMHH+EURM7~4bf                     Type 1C           yes yes yes   7817  0
```

We need to abstract the output. `:P` We can find `Palatino` and e.g, `EURM10`, which is the Euler roman medium font in AMSFonts.